# Confusion about realloc function

Tags: c, language-lawyer, realloc

I read about dynamic memory allocation in C using [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-66/) reference.

That document Say's :

> realloc() should only be used for dynamically allocated memory. If the
>   memory is not dynamically allocated, then behavior is undefined.

If we use `realloc()` something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    int *ptr_new = (int *)realloc(ptr, sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

According to that reference, this program is undefined because pointer ptr not allocated dynamically.

But, If I use something like:

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr = NULL;
    int *ptr_new = (int *)realloc(ptr, sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Is it also undefined behavior according to that reference?

I thing second case does not invoked undefined behaviour. Am I right?

Comment: The document you mention is incomplete. See storyteller's answer below.

Comment: In C you should not cast the return of `realloc` for the same reasons you shouldn't do it for `malloc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first case has undefined behavior, and the second doesn't. In the first case, the value of `ptr` is indeterminate. So passing that value to `realloc` or any function, is undefined by itself.

On the other hand, since `realloc` has well defined behavior when passed a null pointer value (it's just like calling `malloc`)<sup>1</sup>, the second piece of code is perfectly legitimate (other than the fact you don't `free` anything).

---

<sup>1</sup> **7.22.3.5 The realloc function / p3**

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the specified size.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the program almost sure will finish by `segmentation fault` as the linked lists that are created in the heap to find segments are not coherent, in the second case you call the realloc with the NULL first parameter, which means, is a call equivalent to `malloc(size)`

`man realloc` says:

```
   void *malloc(size_t size); 
   void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> If *ptr* is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size

Answer (score 1):

The only authorative reference is the standard document. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the latest C11 standard) has the following to say:

**§7.22.3.5 The `realloc` function, p3**:

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined.  [...]

So, your second example is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first case is obviously undefined behavior because we don't know where the **ptr** is pointing or what the **ptr** is holding at that time. And c standard says that **7.20.3.4.2 The realloc function**

> The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and
>   returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size.

So first case is Undefined behavior.

2. In second case compiler knows what **ptr** has so it is valid but `realloc()`
   will act as `malloc()` according to **7.20.3.4.3 The realloc function**

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the
>   malloc function for the specified size.